# Model, Express e o Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express.js, mongoose

**Possuo o seguinte código no express.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const load = require('express-load');

module.exports = () => {

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//variável de ambiente
app.set('port', 3000);

//middleware
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}) );

app.use(require('express-method-override') () );

//template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//templates
app.set('views', './src/views');

load('models', {cwd: 'src'} )
    .then('controllers')
    .then('routes')
    .into(app);

return app;

}
```

**Arquivo database.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = (uri) => {
mongoose.connect(uri);

//const Product = require('../models/productModel')

mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=> {
    console.log('Mongoose! Conectado em ' + uri);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconected', ()=> {
    console.log('Mongoose! Desconectado em ' + uri);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (erro)=> {
    console.log('Mongoose! Erro na conexao em ' + erro);
});

process.on('SIGINT', ()=> {
    mongoose.connection.close( ()=> {
        console.log('Mongoose! Desconectado. Aplicacao encerrada');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

}
```

**server.js**

```
var http  = require('http');
var app = require('./config/express')();

require('./config/database.js')('mongodb://{minhaconexao}');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Express Server escutando na porta ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para que os models disponíveis na minha aplicação, inciem junto com o servidor. Visto que, com esta implementação, o express não enxerga os models.

No arquivo arquivo do database, se eu remover o comentário, o model do product é criado. Tenho poucos dias de NodeJS + Express e Mongoose, então algumas coisas ainda me parecem confusas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você não precisa carregar todos os módulos se importá-los somente quando precisar utilizá-los. Exemplo de model de User:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Como você deu load em controllers, vou assumir que você utilizará algum deles. Aqui é outro exemplo de um possível UserController:

```
const User = require('../models/User')

class UserController {
  async store (req, res) {
    const { email } = req.body

    if (await User.findOne({ email })) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists' })
    }

    const user = await User.create(req.body)

    return res.json(user)
  }
}

module.exports = new UserController()
```

Acredito que esse exemplo deve ser suficiente para lhe ajudar com esse probleminha.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, sugiro parar de utilizar o express-load, visto que ele não roda bem com classes ES6. Utilize o [consign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consign).

Acho que pra responder essa pergunta, eu precisaria do conteúdo do arquivo `'../models/productModel'`, que você omitiu.

Mas eu garanto que é muito fácil trabalhar com o mongoose. Sugiro seguir o guia básico em https://mongoosejs.com/.

E caso você não se adapte a um ORM como o mongoose, você sempre pode utilizar o [driver do mongodb](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) diretamente.